# Can't retrieve PySerial ListPortInfo.vid, ListPortInfo.pid, ListPortInfo.description

Tags: python, permissions

I am developing a cross platform Python application which will need to work on Windows and Raspberry Pi. I am using 64bit Raspberry Pi OS on a Raspberry Pi 4.

On Windows I have no problem getting via PySerial `ListPortInfo.description`, `ListPortInfo.vid`, `ListPortInfo.pid`. However, on the Pi, description contains 'n/a' and vid and pid contains None. But if I run the script as `sudo` on the Pi, I get the correct information in description, `vid` and `pid`. So it seems to be a permissions problem. Running the script as `sudo` is not an acceptable solution.

I can send/receive data over the serial ports without using `sudo`.

I have played around with the `udev` rules file and `chmod` but I am not a linux person and don't really know what I am doing. Help finding the correct way to set the appropriate permissions would be appreciated.